# PyCharm & Python 3.5: interactive debug shell does not return values

Tags: python, pycharm, python-asyncio

I opened the debug shell in PyCharm, and tried to check the values and objects. It seems that the shell is detached from asyncronous code or something. It does raise an exception when I write an undefined name, but it does not show anything in other cases.

The program that I debug is ran with asyncio:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self._test_insert())
```

What's happening, and how can I get values?

[image]

Doing `await my_var_name` does not fix it.

P.S. I run the tests with Nose.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42981559/edit) to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes placing the code directly in the question rather than posting a screenshot.